# Can 'go install' be used to install a local project not in the current working directory?

Tags: go

I'm working with Go and I'm wondering if it's possible to use `go install` to install a local project that is not in the current working directory. Specifically, I want to install a project from a different directory.

Any insights or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If part of the current module: Yes. If part of the current workspace: Probably yes. Other wise: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command below does the job, by changing directory before running `go install`:

```bash
go install -C /path/to/project/to/install/
```

Answer (score 2):

Go install only works with with the current directory. You are not able to specify the directory you want to install with unless you're using go [workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces). You could run `go install your-module-name`. If you really need to install from a specific directory and aren't using workspaces a possible workaround would be to `cd` into the project you want to install then run `go install` and then `cd` back into your working directory. I.E. `cd ~/path/to/project/to/install; go install; cd ~/path/to/working/directory`